# JVM  Logging Stacktraces

Tags: logging, jvm, java

I have a java application embedded in a executable using JSMooth. JSMooth eats (doesnt display) all the output from system.out and system.err. Is there a way I can turn logging on in the JRE to output all stacktraces when an exception is thrown?

Or someway that I can see the stacktrace for the exception being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a logger like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) to have it output all those messages to a log file.